# Hexagonal maze using Prim Algorithm

Tags: c++, c, maze

I have to create a maze from the Prim algorithm , more precisely with this algorithm: ( Randomized Prim 's algorithm ) . http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation # Randomized_Prim.27s_algorithm

What has this guy is breaking me , " What is the best structure to be used to generate a hexagonal maze of walls ."

How 'm begginer in programming, perhaps you already have more experience would know me indicate a more appropriate structure .

At first glance , I thought of using the Matrix, since the maze will have a pattern of rows X columns ( eg 20x20 ) number .

Could someone point me to a struct ?
I thought about something like :

```
cell typedef
{ 
struct cell * above;   
struct cell * right_top;       
struct cell * lower_right;   
struct cell * lower_left;    
struct cell * top_left;
struct cell * lower;    
} Cell;
```

Answer (score 0):

1.you should learn what is Prim, you could learn it in some algorithm books or MOOC. you could learn DFS, BFS, Prim, and that is enough for this question.
2.When you understand Prim, then you will know how to design cell.

In your code:
you just list all the directions, the important thing is the order and status of how to visit them.